# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/MultipartConfigFactory

Tags: eclipse, dependencies, runtime-error

I've seen quite a few posts about this but can't seem to use them as a fix to my problem. My application is produciing a NoClassDefFoundError on the class MultpartConfigFactory. I am certain that I have it in my dependencies (using maven). It's package is in spring-boot, which I have in my pom.xml file. I have the scope set to compile. Is that the issue? I changed the scope to runtime and got the same error.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/MultipartConfigFactory
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartProperties.createMultipartConfig(MultipartProperties.java:98)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration.multipartConfigElement(MultipartAutoConfiguration.java:59)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba3ce156.CGLIB$multipartConfigElement$1(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba3ce156$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$47c94b34.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba3ce156.multipartConfigElement(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 32 more
```

I've seen a lot of comments about changing the buildpath or the runtime classpath. However, when I got to the classpath tab under run->run configuration, I cannot access specific jars. There is only the large Maven dependencies library there and I can't expand it or anything.

Any thoughts? I've been searching the web far and wide for a day now and can't figure this out :-/

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could shed some light on this problem!

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml as well? I'm solving this issue now and think I can help

Comment: What artifact to use for Maven to download the MultipartConfigFactory class ?